# Javascript add button to table

Tags: javascript, button

This is part of my code for the table. it works but I would like to add button

```
var html = "<table>";

for(var i=0; i<prodArray.length; ++i){
  htmlStr += "<td>" + prodArray[i].name + "</td>";
  htmlStr += "<tr>";
  htmlStr += "<td><img width=200 height=200 src='" + prodArray[i].image_url + 
 "'></td>";
  htmlStr += "<td>" + prodArray[i].price + " coins" + "</td>";
  // This bit with the button is not working
  htmlStr += "<td><button type=button> Click Me!</button"'></td>";
  htmlStr += "</tr>";
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Where do you want to add the button?

Comment: For one thing, you've got `var html = '<table>';`, but then you add to `htmlStr`, a different variable. It would be better if you could use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide an [mcve].

Comment: You have some syntactical issues on line 8. It should be "<td><button type=button> Click Me!</button></td>"; without the quote marks inside the </button> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is better to use ``` `` ``` so it can be easy to read

```js
const prodArray = [{
  name: "user3",
  image_url: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  price: "100"
}, {
  name: "user2",
  image_url: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  price: "100"
}];

var htmlStr = "<table>";

prodArray.map((el, index) => {
  htmlStr += `<td>" ${el.name}"</td>`;
  htmlStr += `<tr>`;
  htmlStr += `<td><img width=200 height=200 src=" ${el.image_url}"></td>`;
  htmlStr += `<td> ${el.price} coins</td>`;
  htmlStr += `<td><button type=button> Click Me!</button></td>`;
  htmlStr += `</tr>`;
})


htmlStr += `</table>`;

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

```html
<div id="table"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a small syntax error breaking your `<button>` tag.

Try this modified code below. Also take care with the variable naming, you're declaring the var "html" but then refer to "htmlStr" in your for-loop.

```
htmlStr += "<td><button type=\"button\"> Click Me!</button></td>";
```

You might find [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) page on w3schools useful for more details on the `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You escaping the quote. Try this:

```
htmlStr += "<td><button type='button'> Click Me!</button></td>";
```